# How to get a list of name arguments in Django's urlpatterns

Tags: django, django-urls

Suppose I have two apps, App1 and App2. I want to get the list of names of each url in `urlpatterns`.

App1 urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = (
    url(regex=r'^$', view=views.index_view, name='index_url'),
    url(regex=r'^about/$', view=views.about_view, name='about_url'),
    url(regex=r'^contact/$', view=views.contact_view, name='contact_url'),
)
```

In App2, I want to get the following list:

```
['index_url', 'about_url', 'contact_url']
```

I can get individual names:

```
>>> import App1.urls
>>> App1.urls.urlpatterns[1].name
'index_url'
```

Technically, I can go over a loop to collect each name in a list. But is there a direct way to get them, like: `App1.urls.urlpatterns.names`?

Comment: Why not something like: `names=[u.name for u in urls.urlpatterns if hasattr(u,'name')]`? I could not find a direct accessor method with a quick scan through the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer:

Use

```
names=[u.name for u in urls.urlpatterns if hasattr(u,'name')]
```

to populate the array of names.

It seems like there is no direct accessor.